# Creating mulitple loops in a sub-category page

Tags: loop

I have a main page that consists of 7 categories being output by wp_list_categories, each li specifically includes one ID. These categories are directed to a category-page.php specifically built for each category. Now, each category has sub categories. So on each of the category pages, I want to build out custom queries for each sub category. Example: the Weightloss category on the main page, links to the category-weightloss.php page. Within Weightloss, there are six sub categories. What is the best way, to create six different queries, in seperate div's, so I can style them? I have looked over WP_Query, but I am not sure of the best, and most appropriate, way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. I use the code below and duplicated it as many times as I needed without any issues so far. If anyone thinks this is incorrect than please comment. I was not using the main loop anywhere else on this page and used WP_Query.

```
<ul class="subcats-list">
<?php
$weightloss = new WP_Query();
$weightloss->query('showposts=5');

while ($weightloss->have_posts()) : $weightloss->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

 </ul><!-- subcat -->
```